# Inheritance vs Specialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, specialization

Considering the following two usage scenarios (exactly as you see them, that is, the end-user will only be interested in using `Vector2_t` and `Vector3_t`):

[1]Inheritance:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> struct VectorBase
{
};

template<typename T> struct Vector2 : VectorBase<T, 2>
{
};

template<typename T> struct Vector3 : VectorBase<T, 3>
{
};

typedef Vector2<float> Vector2_t;
typedef Vector3<float> Vector3_t;
```

[2]Specialization:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> struct Vector
{
};

template<typename T> struct Vector<T, 2>
{
};

template<typename T> struct Vector<T, 3>
{
};

typedef Vector<float, 2> Vector2_t;
typedef Vector<float, 3> Vector3_t;
```

I can't make up my mind as to which is a nicer solution.
The obvious advantage to inheritance is code reuse in the derived classes; a possible disadvantage being performance (bigger size, users may pass by value, etc).
Specialization seems to avoid all that, but at the expense of me having to repeat myself multiple times.

What other advantages/disadvantages did I miss, and in your opinion, which route should I take?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you ultimately want, i think, is to have the user type

```
Vector<T, N>
```

And depending on `N`, the user will get slight different things. The first will not fulfill that, but the second will, on the price of code duplication.

What you can do is to invert the inheritance:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> struct VectorBase 
{
};

template<typename T> struct VectorBase<T, 2>
{
};

template<typename T> struct VectorBase<T, 3>
{
};

template<typename T, size_t N> struct Vector : VectorBase<T, N>
{
};
```

And implement the few functions that depend only on N being some specific value in the appropriate base-class. You may add a protected destructor into them, to prevent users deleting instances of `Vector` through pointers to `VectorBase` (normally they should not even be able to name `VectorBase`: Put those bases in some implementation namespace, like `detail`).

Another idea is to combine this solution with the one mentioned in another answer. Inherit privately (instead of publicly as above) and add wrapper functions into the derived class that call the implementations of the base-class.

Yet another idea is to use just one class and then `enable_if` (using `boost::enable_if`) to enable or disable them for particular values of `N`, or use a int-to-type transformer like this which is much simplier

```
struct anyi { };
template<size_t N> struct i2t : anyi { };

template<typename T, size_t N> struct Vector
{
    // forward to the "real" function
    void some_special_function() { some_special_function(i2t<N>()); }

private:
    // case for N == 2
    void some_special_function(i2t<2>) {
        ...
    }

    // case for N == 3
    void some_special_function(i2t<3>) {
        ...
    }

    // general case
    void some_special_function(anyi) {
        ...
    }
};
```

That way, it is completely transparent to the user of `Vector`. It also won't add any space overhead for compilers doing the empty base class optimization (quite common).

Comment: Most complete answer. Thank you!

Comment: Nice and COOL answer. Takes a guru to get such an elegant answer.

Comment: +1. I suspect your suggestion of enable_if<> in a single class template is the best way -- surely the only differences between the template classes for different vector dimensions would be the number of parameters in the constructor?

Comment: yeah, enable_if would be totally "zero-cost" :) this now hopes to eliminate those i2t objects. although they should be easy to optimize away. a small expression template overloading op, could serve to provide the initializing elements to the ctor. or using op+= like boost::assign would either.

Comment: i thought maybe he wanted to add things like cross product that he only adds for some N like N==3, for which he could use this some_special_function(i2t<3>) or enable_if

Comment: @litb: I like the expression templates idea. :)

Comment: j_random_hacker, something like this i wrote some days ago: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/b6da57ff38dc920a

Answer (score 4):

Use inheritance and private inheritance. And don't use any virtual functions. Since with private inheritance, you don't have is-a, no one will be able to use a baseclas pointer to a derived subclass, and you won't get the slicing problem when passinfg by value.

This gives you the best of both worlds (and indeed it's how most libraries implement many of the STL classes).

From http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/templateInheritance/ (discussing std::vector, not your **V**ector class):

> `vector<T*>` is declared to have a
>   private base of `vector<void*>`. 
>   All functions which place a new element 
>   into the vector, such as `push_back()`, call the 
>   equivalent function on this private base, 
>   so internally our `vector<T*>` is using a 
>   `vector<void*>` for storage. All functions 
>   which return an element from the vector, such as 
>   `front()`, perform a `static_cast` on the 
>   result of calling the equivalent function 
>   on the private base. Since the only way to get a 
>   pointer into the `vector<void*>` (apart from 
>   deliberately dangerous tricks) is through the 
>   interface offered by `vector<T*>` it is safe 
>   to staticly cast the `void*` back to `T*` 
>   (or the `void*&` back to `T*&`, and so on).

In general, if the STL does it like this, it seems like a decent model to emulate.

Comment: A nit-pick: Strictly speaking you do have "is a", but that "is a" isn't public. E.g. a `std:vector<int*>` is a `std:vector<void*>` as a means to implement things with good space efficiency. But that "is a" being private, as far as any code outside is concerned, `std:vectory<int*>` isn't a `std:vectory<void*>` because it can't "see" the relationship. So strictly you do have is-a, but in practice you don't :)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance should only be used to model "is-a". Specialization would be the cleaner alternative. If you need or want to use inheritance for whatever reason, at the very least make it private or protected inheritance, so you don't inherit publicly from a class with a public non-virtual destructor.

Yes, the template metaprogramming guys always do

```
 struct something : something_else {};
```

But those `something`s are *metafunctions* and not meant to be used as types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide the 'correct' answer to the following questions, based on your actual use case and what the real public interface should be:

1. Is "`Vector<T,N>`" your main public interface or an implementation detail? As in, are people supposed to use these objects like `std::vector` or is it simply a way to hide common implementation logic for the real API of "`vector_2`", etc.?
2. Will all "`Vector<T,N>`" have the same logical behavior? Most people will tell you to follow the STL when it comes to these types of decisions, but the STL itself infamously screwed this up with `std::vector<bool>`. And they've been forced to support the resulting mess for 30 years.

One thing to bear in mind is that you can combine both inheritance and template specialization; they're not mutually exclusive. And template specializations should be transparent to users, meaning they should have the same public interface and behavior as the general template.

For example:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class VectorBase {
public:
    // The public interface all 'vector-like' classes must honor
    virtual T& at(size_t index) = 0;

    // More APIs... 
};

// The generic Vector<T,N> 
// Let's forbid inheritance from vectors, for now. 
template <typename T, size_t N> 
class Vector final : public VectorBase<T, N>
{
public: 
   // Have to implement the public interface 
   virtual T& at(size_t index) override;

   // Vector-only APIs
   virtual T* data();
};

// We've got some optimized way of storing, let's say doubles, that doesn't fit the general case
template <size_t N>
class Vector<double, N> final : public VectorBase<double, N>
{
public:
   // Same APIs as baseline Vector<T,N>
   virtual double& at(size_t index) override; 
};

// We DISABLE a specialization, e.g. Vector<bool, N> 
template <size_t N>
class Vector<bool, N> final : public VectorBase<bool, N>
{
};  // Nobody can ever create one of these. We never implemented the pure virtual APIs and we disabled inheritance.

// A different object that has a lot of interface overlap with Vector<T, N>
template <size_t N> 
class Bitset : public Vector<bool, N> 
{
public: 
   // From VectorBase 
   virtual bool& at(size_t index) override; 

   // Unique to me 
   virtual void  bitwise_not(); 
   virtual void  bitwise_or(const Bitset<N>& other); 
   //...
};
```

To share code between the generic "Vector<T,N>" and its specializations, you have several options. The most straightforward way is the put it in protected functions of the base class.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using template specialization too much, you probably need to rethink your design.  Considering that you're hiding it behind a `typedef`, I doubt you need it.